# Apache2 Won't Start

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, webserver, webmin

I have set up ubuntu server on an old pc with webmin as well. I am not sure what was going on but i restarted the server and when it boots it now get this when Apache tries to start.

```
 * Starting web server apache2
apache2: Syntax error on line 237 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default: No such file or directory
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

I have checked this file on this line and it looks like this:

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include sites-enabled/
```

I have removed Apache and re installed it but not sure why it still fails.

Comment: That doesn't look like your apache log, check /var/log/apache2 or /var/log/httpd

Comment: @emsworth this is what i get in the command line i have managed to get to the log and there no entries for the time around when i did try

Comment: I'm not sure I fully  understand, does the file "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default" actually exist?  If it does, is it a symlink or a file?  If it is a symlink, what does it point to?

Comment: @emsworth the file does exist in the sites-enabled folder i checked it am it is a symlink. it is pointing to the ..sites-available/default the only file or folder in the sites-available folder is default-ssl do i just change this to the other file in the folder called kooserver.conf?

Comment: The symlink will need to point to something valid, if kooserver.conf is your configuration, then yes.  Apache includes everything in the sites-enabled directory, and typically the sites-enabled just contains symlinks to the sites-available directory.  This makes it easy to enable and disable sites by adding or removing symlinks, rather than modifying the site configuration files or file locations.

Comment: @emsworth i have changed it too kooserver and kooserver.conf and it still does the same

Comment: Can you show the output of "ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-enabled" and "ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-available"?

Comment: I have just tried this which i have just found on a forum:
root@kooserver:~# sudo a2ensite default
ERROR: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default is a dangling symlink!
ERROR: Site default does not exist!

Comment: remove the symlink to default in the sites-enabled

Comment: root@kooserver:~# ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Oct  9 15:26 000-default -> ../sites-available/default
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Oct  9 14:07 kooserver.conf -> /etc/apache2/sites-available/kooserver.conf

Comment: root@kooserver:~# ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-available
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7469 Feb  7  2012 default-ssl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  156 Oct  9 15:10 kooserver.conf

Comment: @emsworth do you mean delete the file?

Comment: yes, remove sites-enabled/default, it's not pointing to anything

Comment: I have removed it but i now get another error: Starting web server apache2                                                                                               apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
 NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.22:0 has no VirtualHosts
NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
(99)Cannot assign requested address: make_sock: could not bind to address 192.168.1.22:90
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

Comment: That's a whole different issue, probably best to open a new question or search existing ones for the appropriate answer on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As also answered by Qben, the issue was an invalid symlink in the sites-enabled folder.  Removing the broken symlink and adding a valid one will fix the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You do not have a default site enabled:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default: No such file or directory
```

`site-enabled` should contain symlinks to files in `site-available` and I guess your `000-default` symlink does not link to a real file in `site-available`.

I guess this [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/httpd.html) guide might be of interest for you.

Comment: Thanks I have just looked in the sites-enabled folder and there is a file called "000-default" and in the "site-available" folder there is the following files. "default-ssl" and kooserver.conf

Answer (score 2):

One of the reason may be that you might have some site that is not enabled.To check that

1. Go to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`
2. Out of many/some `[sitename].conf` files , one/some may be crossed
3. Delete those found crossed
4. Restart apache server

   > `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Hope this has helped you , but may be some other reason too. Thank you.

Comment: i appreciate your attempt to answer, but try answer like answer not like comment.

Comment: I made some changes , hope this helps !!